# Thu, 15 Dec 2016 05:00:00 EST to Date swift 3 but returns nil

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to convert following date format to Date object but it fails o convert and returns nil.
   Thu, 15 Dec 2016 05:00:00 EST to Date swift 3

```
        let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "EE, dd MMM YYYY hh:mm:ssZ" //Thu, 15 Dec 2016 05:00:00 EST
    guard let date = dateFormater.date(from: self) else {
        return nil
    }
    return date
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: It fails to convert

Comment: Did you search for any of the hundreds questions asking about the same problem? What did you find, and why can't you use those answers?

Comment: You need to supply a `NSLocale` to the DateFormatter. Since you input string is in english and your device language might not be english and therefor it does not understand the `Thu` and `Dec` parts. `NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];`

Comment: Additional note: You may want to use `HH` instead of `hh` since there is no mention of a AM/PM and it should be then in 24h format.

Comment: i tried everythong mentioned here but same issue exisis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. Got guide [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkYVY.png)

```
func toDate()->Date?{
    let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "EE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz" //Thu, 15 Dec 2016 05:00:00 EST
    dateFormater.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    guard let date = dateFormater.date(from: self) else {
        return nil
    }
    return date
}
```

Comment: Better use (rather than your unknown source), as recommended by the Apple's Doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
dateFormater.dateFormat = "EE, dd MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss Z" //Thu, 15 Dec 2016 05:00:00 EST
let stringDate = "Thu, 15 Dec 2016 05:00:00 -0500"
guard let date = dateFormater.date(from: stringDate) else {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: same issue persists